# Return parent record along with all child records using Fetch XML

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-365, fetchxml

I want to return one parent record (Quote) along with all of its child records (Quote Details + linked entity Product) for use in a report using Fetch XML. I am using the Parent Report-Sub Report structure currently, but I need to access data that is stored on the Product in the Parent report.

I have attempted to create a Fetch XML query that fits this scenario, but I have only been able to write a query that returns the pre-filtered Quote header but all Quote Details regardless of which quote it belongs to.

The current Parent Report Fetch XML:

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
  <entity name="quote" enableprefiltering="1" prefilterparametername="CRM_FilteredQuote">
    <attribute name="name" />
    <attribute name="customerid" />
    <attribute name="statecode" />
    <attribute name="totalamount" />
    <attribute name="discountpercentage" />
    <attribute name="description" />
    <attribute name="new_productsubgroupid" />
    <attribute name="new_masterproductgroupid" />
    <attribute name="quotenumber" />
    <attribute name="ownerid" />
    <attribute name="createdon" />
    <attribute name="quoteid" />
    <attribute name="effectiveto" />
    <attribute name="effectivefrom" />
    <order attribute="quotenumber" descending="true" />
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

The current Sub Report Fetch XML:

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
  <entity name="quotedetail">
    <attribute name="productid" />
    <attribute name="productdescription" />
    <attribute name="priceperunit" />
    <attribute name="quantity" />
    <attribute name="extendedamount" />
    <attribute name="quotedetailid" />
    <order attribute="productid" descending="false" />
    <filter type="and">
      <condition attribute="quoteid" operator="eq" uitype="quote" value="@QuoteId" />
    </filter>
    <link-entity name="product" alias="product" to="productid" from="productid" link-type="outer" visible="false">
      <attribute name="price" />
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

My attempt at a combined query (returns a single Quote, but all Quote Details, regardless of parent):

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="true" >
    <entity name="quote" enableprefiltering="1" prefilterparametername="CRM_FilteredQuote" >
        <attribute name="name" />
        <attribute name="customerid" />
        <attribute name="statecode" />
        <attribute name="totalamount" />
        <attribute name="discountpercentage" />
        <attribute name="description" />
        <attribute name="new_productsubgroupid" />
        <attribute name="new_masterproductgroupid" />
        <attribute name="quotenumber" />
        <attribute name="ownerid" />
        <attribute name="createdon" />
        <attribute name="quoteid" />
        <attribute name="effectiveto" />
        <attribute name="effectivefrom" />
        <order attribute="quotenumber" descending="true" />
        <link-entity name="quotedetail" alias="quoteProduct" to="quoteid" from="quoteid" link-type="outer" enableprefiltering="1" prefilterparametername="CRM_FilteredQuote" >
            <attribute name="productid" />
            <attribute name="productdescription" />
            <attribute name="priceperunit" />
            <attribute name="quantity" />
            <attribute name="extendedamount" />
            <attribute name="quotedetailid" />
            <order attribute="productid" descending="false" />
            <link-entity name="product" alias="product" to="productid" from="productid" link-type="outer" visible="false" >
                <attribute name="price" />
                <attribute name="new_submittleurl" />
            </link-entity>
        </link-entity>
    </entity>
</fetch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below query,
What I changed was link-type=“inner” 
Previously you used outer and hence it returned you all the quote details which were not even linked and same with product details.

Let me know if this works for you.

You can try this fetchxml in xrmtoolbox plugin fetchxmlbuilder as well.

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="true" >
    <entity name="quote" enableprefiltering="1" prefilterparametername="CRM_FilteredQuote" >
        <attribute name="name" />
        <attribute name="customerid" />
        <attribute name="statecode" />
        <attribute name="totalamount" />
        <attribute name="discountpercentage" />
        <attribute name="description" />
        <attribute name="new_productsubgroupid" />
        <attribute name="new_masterproductgroupid" />
        <attribute name="quotenumber" />
        <attribute name="ownerid" />
        <attribute name="createdon" />
        <attribute name="quoteid" />
        <attribute name="effectiveto" />
        <attribute name="effectivefrom" />
        <order attribute="quotenumber" descending="true" />
        <link-entity name="quotedetail" alias="quoteProduct" to="quoteid" from="quoteid" intersect="true" enableprefiltering="1" prefilterparametername="CRM_FilteredQuote" >
            <attribute name="productid" />
            <attribute name="productdescription" />
            <attribute name="priceperunit" />
            <attribute name="quantity" />
            <attribute name="extendedamount" />
            <attribute name="quotedetailid" />
            <order attribute="productid" descending="false" />
            <link-entity name="product" alias="product" to="productid" from="productid" intersect="true" visible="false" >
                <attribute name="price" />
                <attribute name="new_submittleurl" />
            </link-entity>
        </link-entity>
    </entity>
</fetch>
```

Comment: Appreciate the response. I am still getting all of the quote details after changing the link type to inner.

Comment: I changed link type to intersect=true.  Could you try with updated fetchxml

Comment: This gives the same result, unfortunately.